# Interpretion of apparent contradition in Numbers 16:38 in relation to fire pans of sinners becoming sacred

Tags: numbers, sinners, altar

In the passage:

> The **fire pans** of those who have **sinned** at the cost of their lives, and let them be made into hammered sheets as plating for the altar—for once they have been used for offering to יהוה, they have become **sacred**—and let them serve as a warning to the people of Israel.

And in Hebrew it is:

> אֵ֡ת מַחְתּוֹת֩ הַֽחַטָּאִ֨ים הָאֵ֜לֶּה בְּנַפְשֹׁתָ֗ם וְעָשׂ֨וּ אֹתָ֜ם רִקֻּעֵ֤י פַחִים֙ צִפּ֣וּי לַמִּזְבֵּ֔חַ כִּֽי־הִקְרִיבֻ֥ם לִפְנֵֽי־יְהֹוָ֖ה וַיִּקְדָּ֑שׁוּ וְיִֽהְי֥וּ לְא֖וֹת לִבְנֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל׃

I didn't comprehend, as it's written in the *caput* of the post, why objects related to sinners become sanctified. Why?

Comment: this is Num 17:3 is other editions of the bible.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is two-fold - partly explicit and partly implicit.

**Explicit Part**

The reason the censor material was sacred = dedicated for a sacred purpose is stated in Num 16:38 -

> ... for these were presented before the LORD, and so have become holy
> ... See also V36.

**Implicit Part**

The censors were used by sinners who attempted to usurp a holy office.  Therefore, they cannot be used by anyone else for such a purpose.  Therefore, Moses was instructed to use the material to cover the altar; thus the censors could never be used again but were to be subject to fire forever on the altar and forever cleansed by fire.  See Num 31:23, Ps 66:10, Ps 17:3, etc.

Comment: But in the text I send it's written that objects used by sinners were santicfied.

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo - that is correct - these objects were "sanctified" that is, set apart for a special purpose - that is all the word means.

Comment: I did not comprehend the relation between your answers and what I asked.

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo - then I do not understand your question.